# How to specify dateparser parsing to treat dd/mm/yyyy as default rather than mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, date, datetime

dateparser package is an awesome one: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

To be generic: i need to be able to parse the dates in a non-US date format.

I am using python 2.7 versions

To be precise: i get -

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('Tue, 06/07/2016')
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 7, 0, 0)
```

i need

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('Tue, 06/07/2016')
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 0, 0)
```

If you know any configuration change that can do this, it'd be great.
any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: dateparser does that for me automatically. Editing the question to make it more readable

Comment: Use `settings={'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'}` keyword-argument to `parse` (Refer to my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dateparser` has `settings` to handle scenarios like that. Instead of specifying date_formats, you can also use `DATE_ORDER` settings as follows.

`In [3]: parse('Tue, 06/07/2016', settings={'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 0, 0)`

Look here for [more settings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to do this rather than `dateparser` as it's part of the standard library for python:

```
In [13]:
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.strptime('Tue, 06/07/2016', '%a, %d/%m/%Y')

Out[13]:
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 0, 0)
```

OK it looks like the comma is upsetting `dateparser`, if you don't pass this in the `formats` arg then it works:

```
In [30]:    
import dateparser
dateparser.parse('Tue, 06/07/2016', date_formats=['%A %d/%m/%Y'])

Out[30]:
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 6, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, but i really want to use dateparser as i can get date in any format. Possible inputs to my program are : "6 June 2015", "16/06/2015", "16\n/06/2015" etc etc. dateparser helps to seamlessly decode these. But i just need the mm/dd/yyyy to be treated as dd/mm/yyyy whenever the case may be.

Comment: Hmm, This only works for just one regex. doesn't work if i supply dateparser.parse('06/07/2016', date_formats=['%A %d/%m/%Y']).

Comment: Why should it work for that? the string format is completely different, you'd need to pass `dateparser.parse('06/07/2016', date_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])` in order for it parse that date, this is why it accepts a string of formats

Comment: basically you'll need to pass a list of formats to handle either format, if something doesn't parse right you need to add further formats: `date_formats=['%d/%m/%Y','%A %d/%m/%Y']` will work with both formats

Comment: Ok. But the whole point of using dateparser gets defeated in that case. it seamlessly extracts date no matter what the format is. I am now forking it to make a indian format. will reply back when its done.

Comment: well you've found that this isn't the case, it seems to me that the `Tue` is irrelevant here, it maybe better to strip the string to just `mm/dd/yyyy` and then you can use a single format that will handle all the dates

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's still facing this issue, you can take a look at the `Settings` documentation dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

As `user739721` has pointed out, you can **and should** use `settings={'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'}` as keyword argument to `parse`.
It can get cumbersome if you have multiple calls to `dateparser.parse()` and adding it everywhere is painful.
For this, one can use `partial` from python's own `functools`

```
import functools
import dateparser
parse = functools.partial(dateparser.parse, settings={'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
```

Now any call to parse will make use of the 'DMY' setting.

**Caution:** In case one ends up passing settings to parse call, the earlier settings get overwritten. So, with above parse definition,

```
In [21]: parse('1 3 1970').strftime("%B")
Out[21]: 'March'

In [22]: parse('1 3 1970', settings={}).strftime("%B")
Out[22]: 'January'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date_formats argument:

```
dateparser.parse('Tue, 06/07/2016', date_formats=['%d %B %Y'])
```

date_formats link https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: still produces `datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 7, 0, 0)`